# Is there any way to convert weight.pt model to weight.h5 or weight.weights to weight.h5 format

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, darknet

Is there any way to convert weight.pt model(weight files in pytorch format) to weight.h5(weight files in keras format) or weight.weights(weight files in darknet format) to weight.h5 format